# Class inaccessible after inheritance

Tags: c++, namespaces

If you compile the code below it fails, saying that class B is inaccessible where it is used as an argument to the member function func. Why is this?

Note: if D2 does not inherit from D1 then the error goes away, so somehow the inheritance from D2 makes B inaccessible.

```
namespace myns {
  class B {};
}

using namespace myns;

class D1 : B {};

class D2 : D1 {
  void func(B b) {}
};
```

Comment: You did a fantastic job of obfuscating your own question by the simple omission of the actual compile error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

Name lookup finds `D2::D1::B`, not `myns::B`. After name lookup, access check is performed, and discovers that `D2::D1::B` is private.

The namespace is a red herring: the exact same outcome is observed if `B` is defined in the global namespace.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the `::` operator. Lookup is finding the injected-class-name instead of the `myns::B`.

```
class D2 : D1 {
  void func(::B b) {}
};
```

11.1p5

> 5 [ Note: In a derived class, the lookup of a base class name will
>   find the injected-class-name instead of the name of the base class in
>   the scope in which it was declared. The injected-class-name might be
>   less accessible than the name of the base class in the scope in which
>   it was declared. —end note ] 
>   [Example:

```
class A { };
class B : private A { };
class C : public B {
  A *p; // error: injected-class-name A is inaccessible
  ::A *q; // OK
};
```

Comment: I'm very interesting why we need class name injection? What the problem it want to solve, any code example?

Comment: @ZijingWu: [Here is one example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9f8eb287c4322bf), would you rather write function `f1` or `f2`? The injected-class-name makes `A f2() {return A();}` possible.

Comment: so injected-class-name is try to make reference class template easier? And even in this case why the base class name also be injected into the scope, which cause a lot of confusing like this post, I see the same question more than once in SO.

Answer (score 0):

The default access specifier when inheriting a class/struct is "private", so your problem is this:

```
class D1 : B {};
class D2 : D1 {};
```

Add the keyword "public" and voila.

http://ideone.com/T5RpUM

```
namespace myns {
  class B {};
}

using namespace myns;

class D1 : public B {};

class D2 : public D1 {
  void func(B b) {}
};

int main() {
    D2 d();
}
```